# Fields "selector" in SELECT request in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use a "joker selector" into a SELECT request, in order to be able to get an undefined number of column according to what is contained in their name?

For example, I want to get all the `%_FK` columns using a request like:

```
SELECT `%_FK`
FROM `table`
WHERE `FILTER` = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more info about this here:

[Selecting all columns that start with XXX using a wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797686/selecting-all-columns-that-start-with-xxx-using-a-wildcard)

I would suggest preparing the column names in your used programming language, and then push them into the query string afterwards.

Comment: I wanted to avoid either preparing names or filtering them afterwards, it could have been quite useful to do it directly in mySQL. Thanks anyway !

Comment: Unfortunately not possible in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You have either to select all columns with `*`  of define the column name explicitly.

If you want to use dynamic SQL you could do something like

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'select id from table';
execute stmt;
```