# MySQL | How to use regular expressions to show columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wanted something like this: 
`SELECT *Name FROM person` 
I would want this to return all the columns whose name has `Name` such as `FirstName, LastName, MiddleName` columns.

Is this possible in mySQL?

Comment: How many "...Name" columns do you have?

Comment: I would just list them all if I were you, I don't predict they would be more than 12 columns

Comment: very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797686/selecting-all-columns-that-start-with-xxx-using-a-wildcard

Comment: If your application doesn't know what the database's schema is there are larger problems at hand.

Comment: I am just getting into databases. And I viewed `*` as a wild card so I thought it would be great/useful if it was possible to use it like that.

Comment: It's not possible, column names must be exact and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Following query can be used to list all fields having name keyword(LIKE operations) in the column name in entire DB exists in MYSQL Server:

```
SELECT 
table_schema "Database", table_name, column_name,ordinal_position "Field Position" 
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name LIKE '%name%'
```