# mysql concatenated string with row value as column name for every row in select query (only by query)

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Below is my table TABLE

```
id   colname1   colname2     colname3
1    Alex       John         Mary
2    Alyssa     Eben         Stephen
3    Sandra     Tina         William
```

I try to use below query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONCAT('colname',id) = 'Eben'
```

I expected the result would be from 2nd row 2nd column. But I get nothing. I referred many solutions which guides to use GROUP_CONCAT but I get nothing worked.
Is this possible to do this with mysql?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because it's treating `CONCAT('colname', id)` as a string, not as the actual columns name. So because 'colname1' = 'Eben' is always false, you'll get no results. Not sure what the solution is yet, which is why I didn't answer, but hopefully understanding why it failed will help haha.

Comment: Thank you. Will try someother way.

Comment: I will do some research as well and post an answer when I find it.

Comment: I've found this, which works if you are looking for a specific id value, but is a little tricky to check across the whole table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282718/dynamic-conversion-of-string-into-column-name-mysql

Comment: Looks like what I expected. tried few times. will give more try until get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dynamic sql. Populate a string variable with your select such as:
  DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE colname@id = ''' + 'Eben' + ''''
Then replace the placeholder string ("@id") with the column number you want such as:
   select REPLACE(@str, '@id', 2)

Last to actually execute the statement simply use "EXEC " + statement. ie: 
   EXEC (@str)

Comment: I am assuming you want to be able to reference a certain column by "colname" concatenated with the ID.

Comment: Sorry Geoffrey. I meant by "You are right" that I want to be able to reference a certain column by "colname" concatenated with the ID. But.. not that the solution worked for me.

Comment: ok. But with the code provided you could do just that (by substituting the string "@id"). Please let me know where the answer is lacking. -thx

Comment: Actually I am unsure how to execute your code since it shows '[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE colname@id = ''' + 'Eben' ' at line 1'.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create another answer because this forum won't allow me to use the @(ampersand) in comments.

```
    DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE colname@id = ''' +    
    'EBEN' + '''' 
    select @str = REPLACE(@str, '@id', 2)
    select @str '@str'  --This is just to examine the code, get the results of     
     --this and run it to test
--you should get this: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE colname2 = 'EBEN'
EXEC (@str) --this will actually execute your code
```

Comment: Is the above query can be used in navicat or should we use it in php? Because still I get the same error.

Comment: I asked the above question because I am familiar with Procedural style mysqli query only and I don't often use object oriented style and why I couldn't successfully run the solution you have given.

Comment: Now I have this code. `$con=new PDO("mysql:host=10.10.10.10;dbname=TABLE","root","root@123");
$query=$con->prepare("DECLARE @str varchar(50) = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE colname@id = ''' + 'EBEN' + '''' select @str = REPLACE(@str, '@id', 2) select @str '@str' EXEC (@str)");
$query->execute();
$result=$query->fetchall();
//echo $result["id"];
foreach ($result as $key=>$value){
 echo $key . "=" . $value;
}
echo count($result);
$con=null;`. This code runs but gives nothing. the count shows zero. Where I could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, not familar with the language you are using (PHP I guess), but could you run the sql steps one at a time? And you proably don't need this bit of code in your sql: select @str '@str'. Also, if in your statement                          $    query=$con->prepare...  couldn't you just use some type of string variable, then that way you only need to do a replace on the string there, not in the sql?

Comment: I think you guide me by using command line sql. if it is then I should improve my knowledge to do that.

Comment: Oh god! I am trying to do this within php and mysql.

Comment: thats ok, you should be able to figure out a way with what I gave you. Don't panic!

Comment: Thanks. Now I am trying to run this query in mysql command line.