# mysql SELECT from column with a concatenated string

Tags: mysql

I select something from a column named "9 stars" (without the "").

```
SELECT `9 stars` FROM `table` WHERE ...
```

works fine, but I have to find a solution to do the job combining a variable `(i = 9)` with the `"stars"`, something like:

```
i = 9;  
SELECT `i stars` FROM `table` WHERE ...  (which does not work like this, of course).
```

Comment: What environment are you in? How is this query getting to MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic conversion of string into column name. MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282718/dynamic-conversion-of-string-into-column-name-mysql)

Comment: Your question is very unclear on what you have and what you need leading to divergent answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to mess around with dynamically constructing your query AND know how many "i" values there are, you could just do this:

```
SET @i = whatever;
SELECT CASE @i 
   WHEN 1 THEN `1 stars`
   WHEN 2 THEN `2 stars`
   WHEN 3 THEN `3 stars`
   WHEN 4 THEN `4 stars`
   WHEN 5 THEN `5 stars`
   WHEN 6 THEN `6 stars`
   etc....
   ELSE NULL
END AS `the_stars`
FROM table
WHERE ...
```

*You could also use the value from another field of the row instead of a session variable (@i)*

Comment: I was going to write this one too, but eating my fruits now :) To be clear because the format doesnt show it. `1 star` is a field name and will return that content

Comment: Question didn't make it clear how consistent the field naming was, so I went with uniformity for the sake of the example.

Comment: @Uueerdo, in this particular case, Your approach seems to be Best.out of the box solution, Great Man! (We should make thing simpler not Complex!)

Comment: btw I think you mean `user variable`  not `session variable`

Comment: This would be good for a limited number of columns, but could get messy real fast if there were more than 5 or 6.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am fairly certain I mean `session`. I believe all single `@` variables are connection(session) specific; I think it is possible to have `global` user variables with `@@`, but am not positive since I have little use for them.

Comment: @miken32 agreed on the feasibility of this kind of solution decreasing with the number of fields chosen in this way; in extreme scenarios the query could actually exceed max length allowed. With fewer fields, this format can be clearer, especially if using another field as the case subject instead of a variable (dynamic sql would involve executing separate queries for each value, or potentially massive unions of such queries.)

Comment: Great, I got it solved with the CASE construction. Maybe not the most universal way for all needs in the future but in my particular case just perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in pure Sql then For Dynamic Column name you need to use **prepare statement**

```
SET @i =9;
SET @table = <tblname>;
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT ',CONCAT('`',@i,' ', 'start','`'),' FROM ', @table);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

check this

[Dynamic conversion of string into column name. MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282718/dynamic-conversion-of-string-into-column-name-mysql)

Comment: Why you nested `CONCAT` ?

Comment: just in case to show him/her that we can make a dynamic query by multiple variable and then we can execute.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza that is a little odd, but should not affect the results; but you did make me notice that developerCK should be including `\`` around the field. `SELECT 9 start from sometable` is not going to work as needed.

Comment: I mean you can concat multiple variables in a single `CONCAT` so no need to nested. Or is there a limit on the number of variables?

Comment: A simpler `CONCAT` would be:
`CONCAT('SELECT \`',@i,' stars\` FROM ', @table);`

Answer (score 1):

Use **[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**

```
SET @i = 9;
SELECT CONCAT(@i,  'stars') 
FROM table WHERE ...
```

Comment: I tried that but as a result of the SELECT I do not get the value of the row but "9 stars" (without "")

Comment: what you mean without the "" ? The result is a string

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza he wants to dynamically select the **field** he is selecting.

Comment: @Uueerdo I know dynamic query, but dont see that in the question, maybe Im too hungry :(

Comment: @Uueerdo Ok I see it now.

Comment: The question is unclear about many things. One of those is that he needs a value of a row in the concatenated string. Just add the field to the `CONCAT` statement

Comment: CONCAT() returns a string, equivalent to `SELECT "9stars" FROM table`. It can not not be used for a column name. This answer should be deleted so as not to mislead future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ELT function in MySQL :

```sql
SET @i = 3;
SELECT ELT(@i, `1 stars`, `2 stars`, `3 stars`, `4 stars`[, ...]) FROM `table` WHERE [...];
```