# Need an SQL query to map column value to column name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have following table structure (Table Name is Questions)

```
c1   c2   c3  Selection

X    Y    Z   2

A    B    C   3
```

Here c1,c2,c3 and Selection are column names. I want to retrieve value of c1 or c2 or c3 on the basis of value of column Selection.
Eg. If Selection value is 2 then I want corresponding value of c2 column i.e. Y.
If Selection value is 3 then it should select value of c3 column which is C here.

Please help me in forming Select Sql query here. I tried myself but was not able to find correct solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: See [mysql field name from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428761/mysql-field-name-from-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE Selection
            WHEN 1 THEN c1
            WHEN 2 THEN c2
            ELSE c3
        END val
FROM    tableName
```

Comment: thanks mate..this is what I wanted...I really appreciate your quick understanding of question and quick reply.... :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to use **CASE's** or **IF's**

```
   select if(selection=2 ,b,if(selection=3,c,a)) from Table1 ;
```

see here for example ... [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bf18/8)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just run a simple query and it will return all the columns then you should use the appropriate column.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE selection = 'yourvalue'
```