# Passing column names as a parameters and calling

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE data1 (IN v_dt2 VARCHAR(256) , v_col2 VARCHAR(256),col2 VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN

 SELECT dt1 as datep, var1 as vars, 'new' as type 
 FROM samp 
 UNION all
 SELECT v_dt2, v_col2, 'col2' as type 
 FROM samp 
 ;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL data1 ("dt2","var2","old")
```

In the above call statement which are in brackets are columns names
but in the output giving the parameters as a text not considering as column names... how to convert them as a column name in select statement after UNION ALL

Comment: Please do not use an ALL-CAPS title, it is distracting and annoying.

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot user variables as column or table names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql field name from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428761/mysql-field-name-from-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is returning *constant* values, not column names.  To do what you want, you need to use dynamic SQL (`prepare` and `exec`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE data1 (IN v_dt2 VARCHAR(256), v_col2 VARCHAR(256), col2 VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
    set @s = '
SELECT dt1 as datep, var1 as vars, ''new'' as type 
FROM samp 
UNION all
SELECT @v_dt2, @v_col2, ''col2'' as type 
FROM samp ';

    set @s = replace(@s, '@v_dt2', v_dt2);
    set @s = replace(@s, '@v_col2', v_col2);
    set @s = replace(@s, '@col2', col2);

    prepare s from @s;
    exec s;

    deallocate prepare s;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon , its throwing error at 'new' ,plz help me

Comment: Don't forget to **DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;** at the end of the SP

Comment: CALL data1 ("dt2","var2","old"), here old is an new variable

Comment: 1054 error am getting like old is not in field list

Comment: @suri5913 . . . That seems strange.  There are quotes around the value in the sql being prepared.